# Public feed Api ,

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-public-feed-api

Want to get Public posts having Specific hashtag and have a specific link, Facebook Search Api for Post is deprecated, Other Way is Found is Public Feed APi My Question is Can we get Public Posts for all Users through Public Feeed Api, if yes then how to access Public Feed APi????

Comment: Could you please try to write complete sentences with proper use of upper and lower case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short Answer: You can´t.

There is the Public Feed API, but you can´t apply to that one - at least not at the moment:

> Access to the Public Feed API is restricted to a limited set of media
>   publishers and usage requires prior approval by Facebook. You cannot
>   apply to use the API at this time.

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/public_feed